# How to Share Hash Table within 2 IIS server

Tags: iis-7, load-balancing, signalr-hub

I have Created a .net core application with signal R, i had also configured Load balancer with it, now the case is i had 2 server, when my application start and user login, signal R create a hash table and store user id with signal R Id, now if there are 2 server then how other server knows about other servers hash table value, is there any better approach use for signal R when we use load balancer.

Thank you,

Comment: That's why people designed NoSQL storage.

Comment: @LexLi is there any other way!! as i heard if i update machine key in iis then it will shared memory and worked, i am not sure, if you had any idea about it then please suggest me..

Comment: I don't know from where you "heard" that, but that seems to be wrong to me.